# Non-latin characters URL rewriting in windows Azure

Tags: php, azure, url-rewriting

I'm checking the possibilities of migration to Windows Azure cloud hosting, the website is using arabic (non-latin) Characters in the URL.

The original url on the website is:
http://nafham.com/%D8%A7%D8%B3%D9%85-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%81%D8%A7%D8%B9%D9%84-%D9%85%D9%86-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%81%D8%B9%D9%84-%D8%BA%D9%8A%D8%B1-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AB%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AB%D9%8A/

On the azure hosting the same URL of the same page is:
http://nafham.azurewebsites.net/%D8%A7%D8%B3%D9%85-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%81%D8%A7%D8%B9%D9%84-%D9%85%D9%86-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%81%D8%B9%D9%84-%D8%BA%D9%8A%D8%B1-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AB%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AB%D9%8A/

On the first url it's running on APACHE server, the url request is working fine.

While on Azure the arabic characters are neglected resulting the request to be the index page

Any ideas on how to allow arabic characters in url for Azure?

Comment: Is the Azure instance also running Apache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like fixing this is fairly involved. There's a [long post here from Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExperimentsInWackinessAllowingPercentsAnglebracketsAndOtherNaughtyThingsInTheASPNETIISRequestURL.aspx). There's also some discussion [here](http://blogs.iis.net/nazim/archive/2011/04/18/use-of-special-characters-like-in-an-iis-url.aspx) and [here](http://blogs.iis.net/wadeh/archive/2011/04/20/how-iis-blocks-characters-in-urls.aspx).

However, you might notice that pretty much everyone thinks this is a bad idea, and that the "fix" is basically turning off a whole series of security checks. It would be better to avoid using percent-encoded URLs and keep the security checks, if at all possible.